# Browse SAPUI5 source code

Tags: sapui5

I require some information about the SAPUI5 core libraries. I want to read the source code of a particular control, for example [sap.m.InputBase](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.InputBase). Where can I find the source for this control? I googled it and found it's in the "InputBase.js" file but what steps do I need to follow to see the source code for this file?

Is there a way I can scroll through the controls in the sap.m library and then read the source code for the control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### OpenUI5

Most of the SAPUI5's libraries, which are opensource, can be browsed [on GitHub](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/tree/master/src/sap.m/src/sap/m). You can even browse different releases by selecting the respective branch:
[image: OpenUI5 branches]

- Here is an example of [InputBase from 1.48](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/rel-1.48/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/InputBase.js).
- Or [filter by filename](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/find/master).

### SAPUI5

Some libraries aren't included in OpenUI5, such as:

- sap.ui.comp
- sap.ushell
- sap.gantt
- sap.viz
- sap.ui.richtexteditor

In this case, download one of the SAPUI5 packages from here: https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/#sapui5 (Scroll down to "SAPUI5 Runtime"). This also allows us to browse the whole UI5 libraries offline without having to run the app.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing this, Was able to find the information i required using your link for Github!

Answer (score 1):

it's to distinguish between openui5 and sapui5. openui5 is the open source clone of sapui5. openu5 is free to use. sapui5 is not. openui5 doesn't contain all controls that sapui5 contains. but openui5 contains all the important basic controls. the controls that are in sapui5 included but not in openui5 are controls like charts and smart contorls that e.g. are automatically configured by odata annotations.

find the source code for the most controls of sapui5 and all controls of openui5 in its github repository [here](https://github.com/SAP/openui5). e.g. find the source code for the inputbase control in its github repository [here](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/InputBase.js).

find the source code of sapui5 or openui5 which is used by a sapui5 or openui5 application through the use of a debugger tool of a browsers on this sapui5 or openui5 application. e.g. to invoke the debugger tool of the chrome browser please press ctrl + shift + i.

[image]

find also the source code for the most controls of sapui5 and all controls of openui5 at the openui5 website [here](http://openui5.org/download.html) in the downloadable runtime and sdk packages of openui5.

find also the source code for the controls of sapui5 and openui5 the sap development website [here](https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/#sapui5) in the downloadable runtime and sdk packages of sapui5.